# Can i join list of classes?

Tags: python, string, class, join, generator

I need to get a string out of the list of classes that have `.__str__()` method.

So **potions** is a list of objects of a class Potion. Potion `__str__` method just returns the name of the potion.
I thought of doing something like this

```
result = "\n".join(potions)
```

but only string can be joined and i dont know how to call `__str__()` for each class inside join.

Or i should do somthing like this:

```
for potion in potions:
    result += "{0}\n".format(potion)
```

Or may be somthing else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly shorter solution:

```
result = "\n".join(map(str, potions))
```

Comment: `map()` is, as far as I've understood, considered less Pythonic than genexprs/list comprehensions, but yeah, that works too. :)

Answer (score 8):

```
result = "\n".join(str(potion) for potion in potions)
```

That is, using a generator expression (could just as well use a list comprehension too --

```
result = "\n".join([str(potion) for potion in potions])
```

to call `str()` for each `potion` in `potions`.